# How to check the connected DB in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am developing in Laravel with read replica configuration.
I added the connection information like this and confirmed that it is actually working.

```php
database.php

'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'read' => [
                'host' => env('READ_DB_HOST'),
                'port' => env('READ_DB_PORT', '3306'),
            ],
            'write' => [
                'host' => env('WRITE_DB_HOST'),
                'port' => env('WRITE_DB_PORT', '3306'),
            ],
            'sticky' => true,
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

However, is there any way to actually check the connection point in the log or dd()?
As a way to check if the connection is currently working, we are in a situation where we are deliberately putting in the wrong value for env information and checking to see if an error occurs.

Comment: How about trying a simple query like e.g. `DB::select("SELECT 1")` and catching any PDO exceptions?

Comment: What are you trying to test? Like, if you put the right values, it will work, period. It was designed for that, don't you trust the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I found a link for you:
[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-check-database-connections-in-laravel#:~:text=Laravel%20database%20configuration%20is%20stored,is%20listed%20inside%20this%20file](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-check-database-connections-in-laravel#:%7E:text=Laravel%20database%20configuration%20is%20stored,is%20listed%20inside%20this%20file).

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class StudentController extends Controller{
   public function index() {
      try {
         $dbconnect = DB::connection()->getPDO();
         $dbname = DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
         echo "Connected successfully to the database. Database name is :".$dbname;
      } catch(Exception $e) {
         echo "Error in connecting to the database";
      }
   }
}
```